# SQL Update statement with a column that has a space

Tags: sql-server

I have come across a situation where a column name in the SQL database is [column name] and I am trying to update it by that column.

Selecting is easy:  Select [column name] from MyDatabase.

I am trying to do this (parameterized):  **UPDATE MyDatabase WHERE [column name] = @[column name]**

the errors say:  **column name does not exist:  @column**

I cant just change the name in the database because it has been around for a while and it will most likely break a bunch of stuff.

Thank you all for your help!

Dave

Comment: UPDATE MyTable,not mYDb

Comment: in sqlserver I think is @variables,parameters cannot have spaces

Comment: If this is SQL-Server specific, please remove the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parametername does not have to match the column name.   (In fact, it cannot have spaces)
Just change your parameter name to not include a space.

```
 UPDATE MyDatabase WHERE [column name] = @columnname
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter/variables cannot have spaces in them. But then again they do not have to match column names.

You can have something like

```
UPDATE MyDatabase WHERE [column name] = @column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx :

> Microsoft SQL Server does not recognize variable names and stored procedure parameters that are delimited. These types of identifiers must comply with the rules for regular identifiers.

This means you can't use `@[variable name]` in your code. You have to make do with `@variable_name` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable WHERE [column name] = @this_is_parameter_name
```